# Case sensitive RLIKE

Tags: mysql, regex

Consider a table `datatbl` like this:

```
+----------+
| strfield |
+----------+
|    abcde |
|    fgHIJ |
|    KLmno |
+----------+
```

I want to write a query something like this:

```
select * from datatbl where strfield rlike '[a-z]*';
```

As in a non-SQL regex, I'd like to return the lowercase row with `abcde`, but not the rows with capitals. I cannot seem to find an easy way to do this. Am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The MySQL REGEXP/RLIKE sucks for this - you need to cast the data `as BINARY` for case sensitive searching:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM datatbl 
 WHERE CAST(strfield  AS BINARY) rlike '[a-z]*';
```

You'll find this raised in the [comments for the REGEXP/RLIKE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Just for future reference, to match the whole string as OP seemed to want, the regex would need to be- `rlike '^[a-z]*$'`

Answer (score 2):

For case-sensitive regex you can use `REGEXP_LIKE()` with match type `c` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(`column`, 'value', 'c');
```

Comment: [Link to documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I've misread OP and this is solution for the opposite case where MySQL is in SENSITIVE collation and you need to compare string in INSENSITIVE way.

#### MySQL 5.x

You can workaround it using [`LOWER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function, too.

```
SELECT * 
FROM datatbl 
WHERE LOWER(strfield) RLIKE '[a-z]*';
```

#### MySQL 8+

If you are running **MySQL 8+**, you can also use case-insensitive switch in [`REGEXP_LIKE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM datatbl 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(strfield, '[a-z]*', 'i');
```