# How to use RLIKE AND regular expression in case insentive

Tags: regex, postgresql, case-sensitive, rlike

I try to only query lowercase results but `LIKE` is not case insensitive.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT
    CITY
FROM
    TARGETS
WHERE
    CITY RLIKE '^b.*n$'
```

the result is

```
BOSTON
boston
```

I want to only keep the 'boston', but I don't know how to do it. I checked this old answer:

[Case sensitive RLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153912/case-sensitive-rlike)

But, the statement `CAST(CITY AS BINARY) RLIKE '^b.*n$'` doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your first problem is there is no `RLIKE` in Postgres. I believe you are looking for the `regexp*` functions here [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html).

Answer (score 1):

`RLIKE` is used in MySQL. The regular expression match operator in Postgres is **`~`**. (Neither is standard SQL.)
`~` is case-sensitive by default.
`~*` is the case-insensitive variant.

This gets you 'boston' but not 'Boston':

```sql
SELECT city
FROM   targets
WHERE  city ~ '^b.*n$';
```

See:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

> but `LIKE` is not case insensitive.

You may have tripped over the double negative there, but "not case insensitive" (i.e. case-sensitive) is what you want. And it's also how `LIKE` works in Postgres (or standard SQL):

```sql
SELECT city
FROM   targets
WHERE  city LIKE 'b%n';
```

If you want case-insensitive, use `ILIKE` in Postgres.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6d729e4397a8c06bf1d7cc4ffbe5992f)*

But MySQL does it differently:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48d1c3245197ff860bc565efaef9041f)*

See:

- [How do you force mysql LIKE to be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007450/how-do-you-force-mysql-like-to-be-case-sensitive)